# Evaluating $\int_0^1 \frac{z \log ^2\left(\sqrt{z^2+1}-1\right)}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} \, dz$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

What kind of *real analysis* tools would you employ for this integral?

$$\int_0^1 \frac{z \log ^2\left(\sqrt{1+z^2}-1\right)}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} \, dz$$

**EDIT:** Here is a *supplementary question*, the cubic log integral version 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{z \log ^3\left(\sqrt{1+z^2}-1\right)}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} \, dz$$

Comment: At first sight, the equivalent integral $$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}-1}\frac{(1+u)\log^2 u}{\sqrt{1-2u-u^2}}\,du$$ looks more manageable.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yeap, it seems so. Let me see the details.

Answer (score 9):

1. Change of variables $y=\sqrt{1-z^2}$ transforms the integral into
   $$\mathcal{I}=\int_0^1\ln^2\left(\sqrt{2-y^2}-1\right)dy.$$
2. Further change of variables $y=\sqrt2 \sin\varphi$ leads to
   $$\mathcal{I}=\sqrt2 \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\cos\varphi\ln^2\left(\sqrt2 \cos\varphi-1\right)d\varphi.$$
3. Next we can integrate once by parts to kill one of the logarithms :
   \begin{align}\mathcal{I}=\ln^2\left(\sqrt2-1\right)+2\sqrt2 \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{\sqrt2\sin\varphi-1}{\sqrt{2}\cos\varphi-1}\sin\varphi\ln\left(\sqrt2 \cos\varphi-1\right)d\varphi.
   \end{align}
4. Finally, pass to a rational parametrization by setting $t=\tan\frac{\varphi}{2}$:
   $$\mathcal{I}=\ln^2\left(\sqrt2-1\right)+8\left(2-\sqrt2\right) \int_{0}^{\sqrt2-1}\frac{t\left(t-1-\sqrt2\right)}{\left(1+t^2\right)^2\left(t-1+\sqrt2\right)}\ln\left(\sqrt2\, \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}-1\right)dt.$$
5. Any antiderivative of the form $\displaystyle\int R_1(t)\ln R_2(t)\,dt$ with rational $R_{1,2}(t)$ can be expressed in terms of dilogarithms. In particular, this is true in our case (use e.g. Mathematica). A fearless reader is invited to simplify the resulting combination of dilogarithm values.

---

6. After a simplification of the dilogarithmic expressions, one finally obtains
   $$\boxed{\quad\displaystyle\mathcal{I}=2\mathbf{K}-\frac{13\pi^2}{48}+\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\ln^22}{4}+\frac{\pi\ln 2}{4}-\ln 2+2\quad}$$
   where $\mathbf{K}$ denotes the [Catalan's constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html).

Comment: Is that “fearless reader”, or “fearless leader” ? :-$)$

Comment: Beautiful closed form (+1). Maybe there is a simple way of getting the result? :-)

Comment: @Chris'ssis Maybe. However in view of the appearance of the Catalan's constant, the "simplicity" will anyway depend on the way of defining $\mathbf{K}$.